# After-hook scenario.exception does not exist in Cucumber 2.0

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm using Capybara, Cucumber, and Selenium-Webdriver for basic web testing. If a test fails, I want to capture the failure message and send it to a separate log file.

Cucumber offers hooks to catch the failure message after the scenario fails (from their wiki):

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
    subject = "[Project X] #{scenario.exception.message}"
    send_failure_email(subject)
  end
end
```

However, when I implement this in my `features/support/support.rb` file, I get a no method error:

```
undefined method `exception' for #<Cucumber::RunningTestCase::Scenario:0x007fc7b4380968>
```

Is this error a result of my setup, or is this a bug specific to Cucumber 2.0?

Here is my code for `features/support/support.rb`:

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

After do |scenario|
    if scenario.failed?
        puts scenario.exception.message
    end
end
```

Here is my code for `features/step_definitions/step_definition.rb`:

```
Given(/^I am on the Google homepage$/) do
  visit 'http://www.google.com'
end

Then(/^I will search for "(.*?)"$/) do |searchText|
  fill_in 'lst-ib', :with => searchText
end

Then(/^I should see "(.*?)"$/) do |expectedText|
  page.should have_content(expectedText)
end

Then(/^I will click the Product link$/) do
  click_link('Product')
end
```

Here is my code for `features/findGameSparks.feature`:

```
Feature: Find the GameSparks Website

Scenario: Search for the website        
    Given I am on the Google homepage
    Then I will search for "GameSparks"
    Then I should see "A NON-EXISTENT STRING CAUSING TEST FAILURE!!!!"
    Then I will click the Product link
```

Here are the version numbers for everything I'm using:

```
OSX 10.10.1
ruby 2.2.1p85
rvm 1.26.11
gem 2.4.6
cucumber 2.0.0
cucumber-core 1.1.3
capybara 2.4.4
selenium-webdriver 2.45.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is fixed in this commit on April 1: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/commit/e92917c8f10a4907dedf26d77665116b69f3e3b9

The most recent release of Cucumber is `2.0.0`, released March 27, so it seems the fix hasn't been released yet.

You can point to the github repo in your Gemfile to get the latest available code:

```
gem 'cucumber', git: 'https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber.git'
```

Note however that running "prerelease" code like this can lead to other problems, for example if a committer to cucumber messes up the master branch.